# How do i transform a column with many different strings into a two level factor column?

Tags: r

Let's say i have collected a sample of garage sales, in that sample there is a column named "Additional Description" and due its optional nature, some entries are empty and others are filled out. If i were to turn this into a factor column, i would end up with about five thousand different levels. Instead i would rather know if having an "Additional Description" helps the garage sale or not.

Because of this i want to turn the empty rows into the factor attribute "N" and the non empty rows into the factor attribute "Y". So in what ways could i go about transforming the data to my liking?

Example:

How the data looks:

```
str(data)
$ Additional Description: chr  NA NA NA "New Products" "Outdoor Sale" ...
```

How i want the data to look:

```
str(data)
$ Additional Description: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Please give an example of the data and the expected output. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `df$newcol <- is.na(df$additional_description)`  or maybe `df$newcol <- df$additional_description == ""`  or maybe something else. Hard to tell without an example.

Comment: You need to post the data in the question, not in a link or a download or a picture.  Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then edit your question accordingly.  Also, this question has nothing to do with RStudio, so please do not add the tag back to it.

Comment: The reducible example is not only needed, because it is hard to describe data in a way that avoids misunderstanding. People who answer questions invest time for free to help others. Preparing sample data takes time as well and if you expect others to help, you should be willing to do that part of the job yourself.

Comment: Example added, this is my first submissions and usage of this website. So excuse me for not knowing the exact guidelines, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to give an example whenever you post a question.
Hoping you want to make empty rows as "N" and non-empty rows as "Y", try this:

```
df$Additional.Description.New[!is.na(df$Additional.Description)] = "Y"
df$Additional.Description.New[is.na(df$Additional.Description)] = "N"
```